# Adobe Flex. How to handle PHP sessions?

Tags: php, apache-flex, session

I am thinking about porting my social netowrking site code to Adobe Flex / PHP and was wondering how does one go about handling sessions in this case.

I would imagine Adobe Flex doesn't really know if a PHP session has been started or not therefore, I would have to research how to accomplish this.

One idea I had was to created a session token string after a successful login and pass this token to each http request the user makes for data.

Eg. http://www.mysite.com/data.php?user=username1&token=d3r3rfewrwer435

Each time a request is made to this page, a MySQL query is run to check if the token I passed in the url matches against the token created for that user during login. If this is true, then data is returned.

This is my idea so far but I am open to suggestions as there's a possibility someone out there has a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

How does your social networking site code currently handle sessions?

Most web sites sync client side requests (AKA A new Page Load) with a server side session using a browser cookie value.

Since the Flash player is a browser based plugin; it can use the same exact method.  When Flex makes a request; all the cookies set in the browser for that domain are sent with it.  This is just like a new page request, or an AJAX Request.

Does that answer the question?